# Finding the home screen's most recent books on Linux

Tags: sony-prs-650, linux

Sony PRS-650 shows the three most recent books on its home screen. How can I modify this top three and how can I list the current ones when the device is connected to a PC running Linux?

Comment: The title needs to be fixed. My first impression was that it was about Linux-running reader.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following shell command for listing the last three files:

```
find database/media/books -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' {} \; \
    | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head -3
```

For putting a book at the top of the list use `touch`:

```
touch database/media/books/mybook.epub
```